# Vuetify Datatables accessibility

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js, accessibility, vuetify-datatable

I'm adding accessibility to my project and I have a basic vuetify data table, just like [this example](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/v-data-table/prop-row-selection.vue), but I can't find a way to make the checkboxes accessible using the tab key on the keyboard, Is there any way to do this? I know there's something called 'tabIndex' and I've used it before, but I don't know how to use it here. Can you guys help me or guide me on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: And what did you try to add `tabindex` to the checkbox?

Comment: hey @Andy this is the code I was mentioning https://codepen.io/EloyFernandes/pen/OJvQxzJ

Comment: It's just the example of veautify documentation

Answer (score 2):

It is very difficult to impossible to “add accessibility” at the end of a project.

Getting keyboard navigation and aria attributes right in 3rd party components is nearly impossible. You’d need to apply plenty of hacks or bind deeply into the component’s DOM, which breaks once the library gets updated.

With Vuetify you chose a library that has accessibility on top of their list, but unfortunately the data table with checkboxes cannot be used by keyboard at all, and is lacking plenty of other ARIA attributes. They don’t seem to keep up to that promise for that component.

As with any 3rd party library, if you find an issue, you should try to [report a bug upstream](https://issues.vuetifyjs.com/) and fix it together with their developers.

### Correct behaviour of data grids

The expected behaviour of tables in web applications is that of a [Data Grid](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/grid/#data-grids-for-presenting-tabular-information).

A data grid is a composite UI component, so it’s expected that the whole component receives focus only once by means of <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then, you’d navigate with arrow keys inside the table, using <kbd>Space</kbd> to select rows or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to interact with a cell.

See [Keyboard Navigation Inside Components](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#kbd_general_within)

You can try [keyboard navigation in AG-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)

The pattern to apply in code would be a [roving tab index](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-6-1-managing-focus-within-components-using-a-roving-tabindex):

Only one child element of the table has `tabindex="0"`, while all others have `tabindex="-1"`. Key bindings then will move the 0 around in the component.

So this is quite some effort to implement.

#### Simple Alternative

As far as I known, it is acceptable—sometimes even expected—by concerned users, for web applications to behave more like websites, where everything is focussed by means of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This might be ok if the only possible interaction in your table is to select checkboxes, and if you provide possibilities to [Bypass Blocks](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#bypass-blocks) by offering landmarks or headlines. You should test it with some screen reader users.

For this to work, you would indeed only need to add `tabindex="0"` to the checkbox.

Then, again, the checkbox does not expose any other accessibility information, it’s an ignorant `<div>`. It should at least be:

`<div role="checkbox" aria-label="Select row 5" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0">`

See [the Checkbox Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/checkbox/)

All this might be possible, see [Vuetify Accessibility (a11y)](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/accessibility/)

### Other Accessibility Criteria

Right now, you mention keyboard navigation. This is a great place to start with, since it is the foundation necessary for most assistive technology.

[The Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) are the reference to look for if you want to achieve compliance. Level AA (including level A) is the one recommended as a baseline.

But be aware that keyboard navigation is only one of 13 guidelines. Exposing state (checked, selected) to assistive technology, or getting contrasts right are examples for other criteria.

For web applications, it’s a good approach to advance the improvements based on critical paths in the story map, similar to an MVP, meaning that you would advance per process/task and make sure that each step in that process is accessible to the audience you prioritised based on the nature of the application.

Usability testing with people with disabilities is also a very good approach that can be applied in parallel, which centres the initiative more on the actual use cases.